# init.d scripts not executed upon startup

Tags: linux, boot, init.d

I have a strange problem on an OpenSuSE11.1 box. Only very few of the init.d scripts for runlevel 3 and 5 are executed, eg. syslog and network. Despite the fact all links in the rcS.d folders are setup for various other services none of them are started (eg. sshd, cron, apache2...).

Unfortunately there is nothing in /var/log/messages which points in the direction of a problem with any of the services that are not started. It seems they are just ignored.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: Can you determine the last one that DOES run properly via /var/log/messages, and check if it's hanging?

Comment: Have you installed any updates to 11.1? I think on 11.3 they started shipping Upstart instead of "good" old System V init, perhaps a check is in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Christophers tip, I could pin down a the problem to a haning start of jexec service. Disabling the service solved the issue. See http://forums.opensuse.org/install-boot-login/402401-boot-hangs-starting-service-jexec.html for details.

Probalbly jexec start fails due to a different default Java that has been installed manually.